# Is a closed set in a metric space necessarily an infinite intersection of open sets? If so, why?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This has been on my mind for a few days now. I know that an infinite intersection of open sets can be closed, but is a closed set necessarily an infinite intersection of open sets?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X, d)$ a metric space and $F \subseteq X$ be closed. If we define

$$ \rho(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, F) := \inf\{ d(x, x') : x' \in F\}, $$

then it is routine to check that $\rho$ is a continuous function with $F = \rho^{-1}(\{0\})$. Then

$$ F = \rho^{-1}(\{0\}) = \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} \rho^{-1}((-\infty, \epsilon)) $$

shows that $F$ is an intersection of open sets.

*Remarks.*

1. $\rho$ is in fact $1$-Lipschitz, meaning that $\left| \rho(y) - \rho(x) \right| \leq d(y, x)$ for all $x, y \in X$.
2. For a general subset $F \subseteq X$, the inverse image $\rho^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the closure of $F$.
3. The set $\rho^{-1}((-\infty, \epsilon)) = \{x \in X : \operatorname{dist}(x,F) < \epsilon\}$ is often called the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $F$ for an obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $C$ a closed subset of $X$. Then $X \setminus C$ is an open set.

For all $x \in X \setminus C$ there exists a radius $r_x>0$ such that the open ball $B(x,r)$ is contained in $X \setminus C$. In particular
$$\overline{B(x, r_x/2)} \subseteq B(x,r_x) \subseteq X \setminus C$$
where $\overline{B(x, r_x/2)}$ denotes the closed ball centered at $x$.

This implies that
$$X \setminus C = \bigcup_{x \in X \setminus C} \overline{B(x, r_x/2)}$$

Using De Morgan's law, this is equivalent to
$$C = \bigcap_{x \in X \setminus C} X \setminus \overline{B(x, r_x/2)}$$
This shows that $C$ is an intersection of open sets.

Comment: Why is it true that the closure of B with halved radius is contained in B?

Comment: Isn't that obvious? For all $y \in \overline{B (x, r/2)}$ you have $$d(x,y) \le r/2 < r$$ thus $y \in B(x,r)$

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far have strived to write the given closed set as the intersection of **countably many** open sets, which is indeed a very useful thing to know, but the OP does not seem to mind the number of sets involved.

If we indeed ignore this point then **every** subset $C\subseteq X$, closed or not, is the intersection of open subsets, namely the sets  $$X\setminus \{x\},$$ where $x$ ranges in $X\setminus C$.